Error de Cors en Laravel al agregar HasApiTokens en el modelo
Ojala me puedan ayudar, me pasa algo raro en Laravel (me estoy iniciando por lo que seguro que algo se me pasa).
Tengo un back en Laravel 11 (api rest) y un front con React. Antes de exponer el error en concreto, os dejo una llamada que si me funciona.
Función en controller en Laravel para cambiar la contraseña:
public function changePassword(Request $request)

    {

        // Valido los datos de entrada

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [

            'token' => 'required|string',

            'password' => 'required|string',

        ]);

        // Existe un email con solicitud de reestablecimiento

        $requested = PasswordResetToken::where('token', $request->token)->first();

        if($requested){

            $user = User::where('email', $requested->email)->first();

            // Confirmo que el email existe y cambio la contraseña

            if ($user) {

                $user->password = Hash::make($request->password);

                $user->save();

                return response()->json(['success' => 'Solicitud correcta'], 200);

            }

            else{

                return response()->json(['error' => 'User not found'], 401);

            }

        }else{

            return response()->json(['error' => 'Error token requested'], 401);

        }

    }

Ahora viene el problema, tengo la siguiente funcion "login" dentro del mismo controlador:
public function login(Request $request)

{

    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');



    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {

        $token = auth()->user()->createToken('Token')->accessToken;

        return response()->json(['token' => $token], 200);

    } else {

        return response()->json(['error' => 'Credenciales incorrectas'], 401);

    }

}

Y al llamarla me da este error: Call to undefined method App\Models\User::createToken()
Entonces me he ido al modelo y he agregado "HasApiTokens" tal y como he googleado...:
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable

{

    use HasApiTokens...

Y al hacer eso, la primera llamada "changePassword" me da error de Cors: "has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'".
Y la segunda llamada "login" ya no me da el error de createToken pero también me da error de Cors: "has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'".
¿Porque al agregar HasApiTokens al modelo User, me aparece error de Cors? ¿Qué hago mal o que me falta controlar?

¿Pudiste solucionarlo? Llevo toda la noche intentando solucionarlo. Intente forzar los headers y muchas cosas. Solo funciona el hasapi y el cors cuando hago pruebas con postman, pero en un navegador siempre ocurre el error que mencionas
